# How to handle an unsecured or incorrectly secured fault in WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have a WebApi project that connects to a WCF service over `https`. This project is installed on 2 different development machines and started locally using IIS Express.

The service works fine on one machine. However, on the other machine, I get the following error:

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

The inner FaultException is:

> Exception during request

The same error happens when running the WebApi on an actual IIS. The code that connects to the service is:

```
EndpointAddress ea = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(url), new DnsEndpointIdentity(identity), new AddressHeaderCollection().ToArray());
MyService service = new MyService(new CustomBindingSecureHeader(), ea);

service.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new CustomMessageInspector());
service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = new X509Certificate2(serverCert);
service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = new X509Certificate2(clientCert, clientPassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

Is there a way to get further details on the exception? Is there something missing in the above code?

Comment: As it says in the message, **See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.**

Comment: If it is working properly in the other machine and other gives that exception, check that the servers clocks are synced. There is a builtin mechanism if there is too much skew in the client/server time.